# Query on triggering build remotely on mutliple conguration project

Tags: jenkins

I have a job which executes on 10 platforms (slaves) but when I trigger the job and see its console output, I see a log message saying,

```
"Started by user <user>
Building remotely on <slave> in workspace: <path>"
Triggering slave1
Triggering slave2
Triggering slave3
Triggering slave4
Triggering slave5
.
.
.
Triggering slave10
```

The `slave` in the above messages is any one of the machines from these 10 slaves and    sometimes it is any other slave which is not related to this job. How is the mechanism in Jenkins by which a `slave` is selected to trigger build on all target slaves?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how a slave is selected for a particular build?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins will look for any available slave and will assign a build to run on that slave. However, if you want to *restrict* the build on any particular slave, then you will have to perform the following steps:

1. `Assign label to your slave nodes`: To do that, go to `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Select a Slave node > Configure`. In this page, you will find a text box called `Name`. Assign a label/name to it. *Perform this activity for all the nodes*.
2. `Tie job/project to a particular node(s)`: Now you have to go to your job's/project's `Configure` section. Look for the check-box named `Restrict where this project can be run`. Enable it. As soon as you will enable the check-box, you will see a text box named `Label Expression`. Assign the name of the node where you want this particular job/project to run. This setting will *tie* the job to that node and the build will *always* run on that particular node. Don't forget to click on the '**?**' mark icon on the extreme left hand side of this option for more details on how you can tie your jobs/projects to multiple nodes etc.

Comment: I am using a multi-configuration project so there is no "Restrict where this project can be rin" section. But it is available in the Advanced project section and I have set it successfully. Thanks a lot. Since I was out for a long weekend took time to respond. Thanks again

Comment: No problem but i'm glad it helped. :)